# Webpack jqgrid error

Tags: jqgrid, webpack

Problem with my webpack build.
I have the following project structure
[image: Look at the image]

```
webpack.config.js:
var path = require("path");
var CommonsChunkPlugin = require("../node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin");
var ProvidePlugin = require("../node_modules/webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendors: [
            './jquery-1.10.2',
            './jquery-ui-1.9.2',            
            './jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en',
            './jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src'
        ],
        pagebbb: "./pageA"
        //pageB: "./pageB"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "jsbuild"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "[id].[hash].chunk.js",
        publicPath: 'jsbuild/'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "jquery": "./jquery-1.10.2",
            "$": "./jquery-1.10.2",
            jQuery: "./jquery-1.10.2"
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: "./jquery-1.10.2",
            $: "./jquery-1.10.2",
            "window.jQuery": "./jquery-1.10.2"
        })
    ]
}
```

on build: 
[image: output image]

Can you give me any advice ?

Comment: Problem with my webpack build.
I have the following project structure. error: http://prntscr.com/8s25h2   project structure: http://prntscr.com/8s25xz

Comment: I don't use webpack myself, but the error message seems that webpack try to search for `./jquery-1.10.2` directly in the directories `./jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/js/i18n/` and `./jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/js/` which is wrong. [The link](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html) describes how one can use **module path** instead of relative path used currently. I suppose it should solve the issue. Moreover I don't recommend to use retro versions of jqGrid like 4.4.0. I recommend you to try [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) instead (see the wiki and readmes for new features)